# In protobuf-net, is there a way to specify a custom method to be used when serializing/deserializing a given type?

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

In [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/) (Marc Gravell implementation), is there a way to specify a custom Serializer/Deserializer to be used everytime protobuf encouters a type to be serialized ?

Something like that :

```
[ProtoContract]
class Foo 
{
    [ProtoMember(1), ProtoSerializer(BarSerializer)]
    public Bar Something { get; set; }
}

class BarSerializer
{
   public void Serialize(object value, Protowriter writer)
   {
       //do something here with writer...
   }
}
```

I looked at the docs but could not find anything.
I know this is possible to use `Protowriter` directly to serialize an object (like this [DataTable](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/DataTableSerializer/Program.cs) example).

What I would like to do is to use the custom serializer only for a given type and use default implementation for the other types already implemented (eg : int, string, ...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, basically. But what you *can* do is write a second **type** (a surrogate type) that is used for serialization. This type needs to have conversion operators between the two types (declared on either, usually the surrogate), and be registered into the library, for example:

```
RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(Foo)].SetSurrogate(typeof(FooSurrogate));
```

The library still controls how `FooSurrogate` is written on the wire. There is not currently an API that allows you to directly control the output *inside* a type. But if you start from `ProtoWriter` you can of course do everything manually.